# why must use const reference when reference to literals

Tags: c++, reference, constants, literals

I know only object could have reference. But literals are not object.
So I could understand why following code cannot compile:

```
int &a = '4';
int &b = 2;
```

However, when I add **const** in front of them, it could work!!

```
const int &a = '4';
const int &b = 2;
```

I do not know why. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A integer or character literal is a prvalue [expr.prim.general]

> A literal is a primary expression. Its type depends on its form (2.13). A string literal is an lvalue; all other literals are prvalues.

Since it is a prvalue we are allowed to take a `const &` to it but we cannot take a reference to it.  If we take a `const &` to the temporary the the lifetime of the temporary will be extended to the point where the reference goes out of scope.

```
{
    const int & a = 42;
    //line of code
    //42 still exits here
} // a goes out of scope and now 42 is gone
```

Answer (score 0):

(Assiming that you left out '&' in the second snippet.)

Because the literal is not an object; a temporary object is created which has the value corresponding to the literal.

You can bind a temporary to a const reference, and thereby extend that object's lifetime, but you can't bind it to a non-const reference.

Comment: what is the mean of _object's lifetime_ here? why I need to extend it?